# How can I make a Flutter desktop app single-instance?

Tags: flutter, dart, instance, mutex

I have a Flutter desktop application and wanted to prevent multiple instances of it from running at the same time. I tried to use `Mutex` from `package:mutex` for that, but it doesn't work.  Can anyone correct it for me or tell me any other way to do that?

This is my code:

```dart
import 'package:mutex/mutex.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  final mutex = Mutex();
  if (await mutex.acquire() == null) {
    runApp(MyApp());
    mutex.release();
  } else {
    // The mutex is already held by another instance of the app.
    // You can choose to show an error message or just exit silently.
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `package:mutex` is meant to provide a locking mechanism *within* a process (and specifically within a single isolate), not across processes.  You would need to find some other (possibly platform-specific) approach.

Comment: Open a `ServerSocket` on a fixed port. If you succeed, `runApp`, else, another instance is already running.